# React Navigation v5: create custom navigator causes error 'Element type is invalid expected a string but got undefined'

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm trying to extending a built-in navigator based on the document https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/

However, I got the error message 'Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got undefined'

The source code can be found here: https://snack.expo.io/qpheiR2qV

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your `createTabNavigatorWithRouter(MyTabRouter)` returns the value from `createNavigatorFactory`. The `createNavigatorFactory` function returns a function to create a navigator.

Instead of

```js
const Tab = createTabNavigatorWithRouter(MyTabRouter)
```

You have

```js
const createTabNavigator = createTabNavigatorWithRouter(MyTabRouter)
```

Then you can use it to create a navigator:

```js
const Tab = createTabNavigator();
```

Docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigators/#createnavigatorfactory

Though I'm not sure what your router is trying to do. Looks like it prevents switching back to a previous tab.